# python OpenCV mask ROI of a PCB trace

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a gray-scaled image of a printed circuit board. I would like to highlight the trace connection from point A to point B if I double click on either point. I see the gray intensity different here (pad, trace, and area around trace with higher, medium, and lower gray value respectively), but I do not know how to accomplish this with `python-OpenCV`.

Is there an existing algorithm to mask a ROI of the trace connection with the gray-value intensity difference like how I describe above i.e., not a rectangular or circular ROI? Something similar to loop from mouse-clicked pixel to all direction, check the intensity change, then mask the ROI that covers only the trace area?

[image: Annotated Image]

[image: Original Image]

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-detect-and-highlight-small-pcb-circuit-trace/8661

Comment: and I'll say the same here: thresholding (copper/no-copper) and connected components analysis, or floodfill. the image contains some artefacts that will make this difficult, like brighter areas causing their surroundings to become darker.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I will try it out. Also, the `Wand Tool` functionality of `ImageJ` also serves this purpose very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find [ImageJ Wand Tool](https://github.com/imagej/ImageJ/blob/master/ij/gui/Wand.java) is a very nice algorithm for this. I re-write the `autoOutline` function (in `FourConnected` mode without inner-hole detection). I then create a filled Polygon with the results sets of points.
The `TraceEdge` function is mainly what I am looking for.